# How come .appendTo works on one page but not another?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, append, appendto

So I'm using jQuery mobile and I'm trying to move an item from one list to another.  I have this:

```
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.green, .blue, .red').click(function(){
        var $move = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]').appendTo("#summary .theListItem");
    });
});
```

Which works beautifully when moving an item on the same list on the same page.  Yet it won't move it to the other list on the other page even if I specify that div.  Here is my html on summary.html:

```
<ul id="thelist" data-corners= "false" >
 <div id="summary">
  <div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a" style= "background-color: #0066cc;">
       <h3>I want it to show here</h3>
       <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
         <a class= "green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">Tax deductible</a>
         <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">Not deductible</a>
         <a class="blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button">I don't know</a>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </ul>
```

Here is my html on trans.html:

```
<ul id="thelist" data-corners= "false" >
  <div class = "theListItem" data-role="collapsible-set" data-collapsed="false">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" data-theme="a" style= "background-color: #0066cc;">
       <h3>I want this to move</h3>
       <div data-role="controlgroup"  data-type="horizontal">
         <a class= "green" href="categorize.html" data-transition="slide" data-role="button">Tax deductible</a>
         <a class="red" href="#" data-role="button">Not deductible</a>
         <a class="blue" href="IDontKnow.html" data-transition="slideup" data-role="button">I don't know</a>
       </div>
     </div>
 </ul>
```

And here is the identical head of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>My Page</title> 

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

<script src="js/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>
--><script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.js"></script>
<!--<script src="jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-rc.2.min.css"></script>-->


<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript" src="cubiq-iscroll-bad88fb/src/iscroll.js"></script>    

<script src="js/scrollbar.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jQueryMobileStructure.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nikostyle.css" /> 

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


</head>
```

Thanks so much

Comment: Which other page? Are you talking about inter-tab communication?

Comment: Maybe, I'm not sure.  I have list items on trans.html and I'm moving them to a list on summary.html.  I'm using jQuery Mobile and since it uses Ajax it doesn't always refresh like a normal web site.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Do you open a new window with one page from the other? Or, do you navigate from one to the other (then they don't exist at the same time)? Or, are both pages open separately by the user?

Comment: It scrolls from one page to another without opening a new window or tab.  It is the same window and it doesn't refresh.  Is that why?

Comment: So, the second page is loaded through AJAX? Are you trying to modify it before it's loaded?

Comment: How (and when) do you load (not show) the second page? If it's loaded through AJAX, then it doesn't need to carry it's own jQuery.

Comment: I suppose.  The css and html will load but none of the jQuery.  I have to refresh each page for the jQuery to work properly, and I guess that once i do that I reset the page to the original html and hence don't see the appendTo in effect.  But if that's the case than it should at least disappear from trans.html when i click the button , yet it doesn't.  So I'm still a bit confused.  Thanks for the help th:o)

Comment: With jQuery Mobile I believe that the head of the entire App is loaded all at once, from whichever page you load first.  My head is identical on every page tho, so it should work.

Comment: Now I'm utterly confused. Can you show me the code that relates to opening the second page?

Comment: What do you mean by "scrolls to"? Do you mean the usual "scrolls to" as in "document moves upwards to reveal new content" or the less usual "scrolls to" as in "the web browser performs a scrolling animation to indicate a new page has been opened (navigated to)"?

Comment: If navigation occurs, then the page you're trying to modify does not exist at the moment you're trying to modify it.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile standard navigation will not call document.ready when you change your page. 
I see two possible solutions:

1. Use pageinit event instead of document ready (as described [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/events.html))

   ```
    $(document).on('pageinit','[data-role=page]', function() {
       $('.green, .blue, .red').click(function(){
           var $move = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]').appendTo("#summary .theListItem");
       });
   });
   ```
2. Or, you could bind your events at the document level and they should apply throughout your application, whatever page the user might have navigated to (since the document remains the same wit jquery mobile ajax navigation)

   ```
   $(document).on("click", ".green, .blue, .red", function(){
       var $move = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]').appendTo("#summary .theListItem");
   });
   ```

Comment: Like this? `$('document').bind('pageinit', function(){
$("body").on("click", ".green, .blue, .red", function(){
    var $move = $(this).closest('div[data-theme="a"]').appendTo("#summary .theListItem");
});
});
`

Comment: that's a bit overkill, you can either use 'pageinit' and bind like you did, or keep your document ready event but bind using "on" as in option 2 instead of binding with .click()

Comment: I don't really understand. :/ Anyway u can just write it out? Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: you can use either one of the solutions provided, both should work. no need to mix the two